# Is there an epistemological word that means "one who solicits prostitutes"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I'm not certain that I'm phrasing my question correctly, but I couldn't think of a better way to word it. What I'm asking is for a word that truly defines to mean a person who solicits prostitutes. I've heard of the slang word "john", but that's not a satisfying answer to me. "Whore" and "prostitute" unambiguously mean a person, connotatively female, who trades sexual favors for money, with whore being more derogatory and prostitute more meaning the actual profession. "John" doesn't quite do this, it's meaning isn't so clearly explicit in the word.

So, is there a word that does this? As a secondary question, if there is not a word in English, is there one in another language?

An example of how this word would be used: We can't keep the *blanks* away from the new escort service that opened downtown.

Comment: A whore is a woman who sleeps around, not necessarily for money. A prostitute sleeps with people to pay rent.

Comment: Please note "solicit" has the exact opposite sense to what is needed here. A "prostitute" *solicits*, a "prospective customer" doesn't -- perhaps *enquires*, rather.

Comment: "Epistemological" and "truly defines" are not clear. It seems from those qualifications you're looking for a neutral term, not judgmental and not derogatory, for a male customer who pays an adult female to engage in some sex act with him. But your example seems more colloquial, and would admit a slang term. Which is it?

Comment: prostitution and epistemology is like garbage in a math treatise.

Comment: Wikipedia has a section on [nomenclature for clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution#Clients).

Answer (score 4):

In the US and Britain, the crime of offering to pay for sex is called *solicitation*, which is always illegal in the US and illegal in public in Britain.  The term *solicitor*, however, was already taken. [Insert your own prostitution joke here]  Traditionally, no matter what the law said, authorities penalized the seller and ignored the buyer.  Where the law has reversed that (e.g., Sweden), the shaming term of art is **sex buyer**.  Where the law has butted out (e.g., Holland), the more neutral term is **client**.  Anglophone prostitutes (which isn't as seamy as it sounds) call their customers, **johns**, **tricks**, or **scores**.

Comment: Also [punter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution#Clients) in the UK (similar status to "john" or "trick" in US).

Answer (score 3):

Whoremonger, defined by Merriam-Webster as 'whoremaster,'
which it in turn defines as

> a man consorting with whores or given to lechery

[Whoremonger](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whoremonger), [Whoremaster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whoremaster)

This is, by definition the word you are looking for.

Comment: You need to put the definition in the answer, not merely assert that your link is definitive.

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to think of a word in English, but the French term for a hooker's client is [**micheton**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/french-english/micheton).

> *Blanche has been driven around by cabbies who claim to be gentlemen temporarily down on their luck, and spent high-paid nights with
>   **michetons** who boast that they began as coal miners*. [Miami
>   Herald](http://www.miamiherald.com/entertainment/books/article2087754.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Patron](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patron) might be a good candidate as it means:

> A regular customer, as of a certain store or restaurant. [Wiktionary]

Its verb form "[patronize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patronize)" means:

> To go to as a customer, especially on a regular basis [The Free Dictionary]

It is broadly used in the media and the law to mean the opposite of *solicit*:

The following in NY Times shows its usage:

Without sex buyers, there wouldn’t be sex trafficking. Currently, however, buyers are not being prosecuted under federal law. Representatives Ted Poe and Carolyn Maloney and others have introduced an important bill that would remedy this by expanding the Trafficking Victims Protection Act to penalize those who ***[solicit or patronize](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/08/06/opinion/prosecuting-sex-buyers.html)*** sex trafficking victims.

[Solicit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solicit) means:

> To offer to perform sexual activity, especially when for a payment. [Wiktionary]

Answer (score 0):

The terms ["Monger"](https://www.nbcbayarea.com/news/local/sex-review-boards-internet/151516/)  and ["Hobbyist"](https://www.vice.com/en/article/exkkm7/we-spoke-a-sex-industry-hobbyist-the-worst-kind-of-john) are in current use in online sex sites

Comment: Can you find another reference for this? For the people who don't want to visit a "sex site" :/

Answer (score -2):

Sex Client would be the usual description of that person.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would benefit from some supporting references and explanations as to why you would choose that term.